# Using a duration field in a Rails model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, time, duration

I'm looking for the best way to use a duration field in a Rails model.  I would like the format to be HH:MM:SS (ex: 01:30:23).  The database in use is sqlite locally and Postgres in production.

I would also like to work with this field so I can take a look at all of the objects in the field and come up with the total time of all objects in that model and end up with something like:

> 30 records totaling 45 hours, 25 minutes, and 34 seconds.

So what would work best for?

- Field type for the migration
- Form field for the CRUD forms (hour, minute, second drop downs?)
- Least expensive method to generate the total duration of all records in the model

Answer (score 46, accepted):

- Store as integers in your database (number of seconds, probably).
- Your entry form will depend on the exact use case. Dropdowns are painful; better to use small text fields for duration in hours + minutes + seconds.
- Simply run a `SUM` query over the duration column to produce a grand total. If you use integers, this is easy and fast.

Additionally:

- Use a helper to display the duration in your views. You can easily convert a duration as integer of seconds to `ActiveSupport::Duration` by using `123.seconds` (replace `123` with the integer from the database). Use `inspect` on the resulting `Duration` for nice formatting. (It is not perfect. You may want to write something yourself.)
- In your model, you'll probably want attribute readers and writers that return/take `ActiveSupport::Duration` objects, rather than integers. Simply define `duration=(new_duration)` and `duration`, which internally call `read_attribute` / `write_attribute` with integer arguments.

Comment: I never did consider using seconds, doh!  Thanks for the tip!

Comment: How do you use `inspect` to format the output? Example?

Answer (score 28):

In Rails 5, you can use ActiveRecord::Attributes to store ActiveSupport::Durations as ISO8601 strings. The advantage of using ActiveSupport::Duration over integers is that you can use them for date/time calculations right out of the box. You can do things like `Time.now + 1.month` and it's always correct.

Here's how:

Add `config/initializers/duration_type.rb`

```
class DurationType < ActiveRecord::Type::String
  def cast(value)
    return value if value.blank? || value.is_a?(ActiveSupport::Duration)

    ActiveSupport::Duration.parse(value)
  end

  def serialize(duration)
    duration ? duration.iso8601 : nil
  end
end

ActiveRecord::Type.register(:duration, DurationType)
```

Migration

```
create_table :somethings do |t|
  t.string :duration
end
```

Model

```
class Something < ApplicationRecord
  attribute :duration, :duration
end
```

Usage

```
something = Something.new
something.duration = 1.year    # 1 year
something.duration = nil
something.duration = "P2M3D"   # 2 months, 3 days (ISO8601 string)
Time.now + something.duration  # calculation is always correct
```

Comment: I've tried this in a rails engine and when I `db:migrate`, the command doesn't report an error but the generated schema contains 
`# Could not dump table "mynamespace_mytable" because of following StandardError
#   Unknown type 'duration' for column 'duration_column'`

Comment: My mistake was trying to use `:duration` as the column type

Answer (score 6):

I tried using ActiveSupport::Duration but had trouble getting the output to be clear.

You may like [ruby-duration](https://github.com/peleteiro/ruby-duration), an immutable type that represents some amount of time with accuracy in seconds. It has lots of tests and a Mongoid model field type.

I wanted to also easily parse human duration strings so I went with [Chronic Duration](https://github.com/hpoydar/chronic_duration). Here's an example of adding it to a model that has a time_spent in seconds field.

```
class Completion < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :task
  belongs_to :user

  def time_spent_text
    ChronicDuration.output time_spent
  end

  def time_spent_text= text
    self.time_spent = ChronicDuration.parse text
    logger.debug "time_spent: '#{self.time_spent_text}' for text '#{text}'"
  end

end
```

Answer (score 4):

I've wrote a some stub to support and use PostgreSQL's `interval` type as `ActiveRecord::Duration`.

See this gist (you can use it as initializer in Rails 4.1): https://gist.github.com/Envek/7077bfc36b17233f60ad

Also I've opened pull requests to the Rails there:
https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/16919

Comment: We wrote an updated gist for Rails 5.1: https://gist.github.com/vollnhals/a7d2ce1c077ae2289056afdf7bba094a

Comment: @Envek thanks mate you saved me a lot of time. Here is the final PR: https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/0475215d4fa1a6db2a92a0065081fe19c64cc124